# jQuery create multi-level unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to create a multi-level unordered list with jQuery.

In reality i'm sticking this into the jQuery autocomplete plugin, but i've dumbed down a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/378rc/4/) keep it simple with hardcoded data and without the plugin.

First the hardcoded output (what i want to see), then the dynamic output (with the code im trying).

You can see what i've tried, but i'm not having too much luck so far. :)

Can anyone help me out? Or has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to work with the categoryID's:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/378rc/9/)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Ahh, i didnt think about actually going and finding the elements by id, i was thinking old school loop builders, based on a known order. Works though - thanks!